# jupyter_notebook_config.py: which argument sets the location of the 'download as' file for jupyter notebook?

Tags: config, jupyter-notebook

I want to set the 'Download as' location for export files from Jupyter Notebook as os.getcwd(), the directory of the ipython notebook. Presently on my mac it defaults to the downloads folder, which is my browser default. Does anyone know which argument sets this location in the jupyter_notebook_config.py file? Or whether this can be set at all?

This is a link to the documents: [Read the Docs - Config File](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers (and the browser user) control the destination for downloaded files.  The server can't specify it; it would be a security risk if it could.

Comment: Okay, so the answer then is to change it in the browser preferences. Or write a script that kicks the output to the work directory. Not the answer I wanted, but thank you for your response. I'll solve the problem another way.